# Can I Develop a DirectShow Filter with Electron framework?

Tags: javascript, filter, electron, frameworks, directshow

Can I Develop a DirectShow Filter with Electron framework or at least with any JavaScript framework?

Answer (score 0):

DirectShow filters are typically developed in C++.

There were some efforts to implement them in Delphi and C#.

There is no way to implement a full filter in JavaScript. The closest to imagine is to develop a filter and design a callback or other interoperation mechanism to communicate with JavaScript code.